# How can I catch dialog tab change in CKEditor 4?

Tags: javascript, events, dialog, ckeditor

It seems there's no event triggered on dialog tab change. Is there any way to trigger some function when a dialog tab is shown/changed/clicked?

I mean the moment it's clicked or shown, but NOT just getting active tab on some dialog element change or `onOk`.

I'm using the latest CKEditor 4.4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dialog event "selectPage" (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog-event-selectPage)

for example:

```
 return {
         title : editor.lang.googlemaps.title,
         minWidth : 500,
         minHeight : 460,
         onLoad : function()
         {
            this.on('selectPage', function (e) {
               // your code
            });
         }
}
```

source:
http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/How-add-selectPage-listener

Answer (score 1):

```
dialog.on("selectPage", function (ev) {
            console.log("changed");
        })
```